# iFrame target ignored after random number of clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

On this page: http://corpapps.parker.com/corpapps/interactive_product_selector/Front_Loader_Selector_05.html

I have a section of visibility toggled divs, each one with an image map.

The tab links and the hotspots all point to an iFrame (**iframe_PSD**) to open a remote page.

The problem is, when a user clicks the tabs and hotspots, which *do* open the remote page in the iFrame, at some random point, the links begin opening in a new browser tab, ignoring the target="**iframe_PSD**"! From that point, every click will open the remote page in the new browser tab.

Tested in the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Has anyone ever heard of this issue? Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can click the tab links all day, it's only the hotspot links that, after a few clicks, suddenly begin to open the remote page in a new browser window.

After that malfunction occurs, then even the tab links begin to do the same.

Comment: I cleaned up the code, so this is a better example:

http://corpapps.parker.com/corpapps/interactive_product_selector/Front_Loader_Selector_07.html

I removed all the href's and am using only 'window.open', interesting thing is that all the hotspots in the first two tabs work just fine (pump and valves) but the hotspots in the other tabs only take 2 or 3 clicks to produce the error. The hotspot links are all formatted identically, why do you suppose the ones in the last 3 tabs are producing errors while the ones in the first two tabs seem to work perfectly?